# Is it possible to change logname for nginx dymanically?

Tags: nginx

Can I change  logname dynamicaly ( for example : '2011-11-31.log' ) for nginx without logrotate,etc ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write and put a bash script into your cron daily folder to parse your conf file, change the logname and reload nginx to achieve this.

Potentially a bit of wheel reinvention in that though.
See Logrotate dateext option: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Rename them to your desired name, then tell nginx to re-open the logfiles, either with `nginx -s reopen` or `kill -HUP $(pidof nginx)`. Give worker processes a little time to finish writing, commence further processing (compression, moving, etc.)

[Nginx's documentation details this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html).